# Limit traversal to a particular depth in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

Consider the code

```
int numberOfFriends = 0;
String output = neoNode.getProperty( "name" ) + "'s friends:\n";
Traverser friendsTraverser = getFriends( neoNode );
for ( Path friendPath : friendsTraverser )
{
output += "At depth " + friendPath.length() + " => "
          + friendPath.endNode()
                  .getProperty( "name" ) + "\n";
numberOfFriends++;
}
output += "Number of friends found: " + numberOfFriends + "\n";
```

Which will give us the following output:

```
Thomas Anderson's friends:
At depth 1 => Trinity
At depth 1 => Morpheus
At depth 2 => Cypher
At depth 3 => Agent Smith
Number of friends found: 4
```

I want to limit the search to depth 2. What should i do?

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
Traversal.description().evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(2))
```

Comment: More info here: http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Evaluators.html